# How to configure Oracle Client with Qt?

Tags: c++, oracle, qt

I am trying to connect to Oracle database in a Qt application. I just created a sample code like below to first test the database connectivity.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QOCI");
    db.setHostName("192.168.1.11");
    db.setDatabaseName("dm1db");
    db.setUserName("user");
    db.setPassword("user123");
    bool ok = db.open();
}
```

It is saying

```
QSqlDatabase: QOCI driver not loaded.
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

This happened two days before and I understood that the QOCI is not enabled in my Qt Creator installation. So I tried to enable it by following the below guidance by Qt.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html

I am having a Oracle 12.1.0.2 client. The files are (/home/santhosh/instantclient_12_1) :

[image: oracle client lib files]

Include files (/home/santhosh/instantclient_12_1/sdk/include):

[image: oracle client include files]

Oracle 12.1.0.2 client contains libclntsh.so.12.1 file only. So I created a symlink to that file as libclntsh.so in the same directory to support the naming conversion as per the Qt documentation.

I tried this command as per the Qt documentation to enable the OCI driver.

```
./configure -sql-oci OCI_INCDIR=/home/santhosh/instantclient_12_1/sdk/include OCI_LIBDIR=/home/santhosh/instantclient_12_1
```

But when it finishes it gives me an error like:

```
ERROR: Feature 'sql-oci' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'libs.oci' failed.
```

I found this error in the config.log file.

```
    loaded result for library config.qtbase_sqldrivers.libraries.oci
Trying source 0 (type inline) of library oci ...
  => source failed condition 'config.win32'.
Trying source 1 (type inline) of library oci ...
oci.h not found in [] and global paths.
  => source produced no result.
test config.qtbase_sqldrivers.libraries.oci FAILED
```

I tried few other different ways in last two days following some other documentation on enabling oci in Qt. But nothing is working for me. The Qt documentation is not clear about what to do for the naming conversion of the oracle .so file in the latest clients like above one.
I am using:

[image: My Qt Version detail]

Can anyone tell me an exact step by step process I should follow to configure my Qt Creator to work with my Oracle database?

Comment: I would like to add few other details like below:

1. The Oracle client I mentioned in the above question is actually working perfectly for all other applications like PyCharm (for PyQt5).

2. Oracle client is also 64 bit binary only.